# In what way does my unconscious belong to me?

Tags: consciousness

I've studied 'subconscious' a little, in terms of sense processing of things outside of conscious awareness and Buddhist theories of continuity, and I am familiar with Freud's 'unconscious'. In what way can e.g. the perception of a patch of colour changing *belong* to me (let's suppose I perceive it change, outside conscious awareness) if it does not exist in consciousness (qualitatively or as self cognition)?

I am wondering whether the 'subconscious' includes experiences e.g. of tissue damage without consciousness of pain (vice versa?), especially how to think of the **effects** of the relevant events on consciousness, and whether personal identity and/or perceptual integrity at any time depends on that.

What philosophers (of psychology, psychoanalysis, religion) have usefully talked about how the limits of consciousness might occur before - or be contained within - those of (subconscious) awareness?

Comment: "*Where id was, ego shall be*", [from the horse's mouth](https://daily.jstor.org/virtual-roundtable-on-the-ego-and-the-id/).

Comment: The arrogance of ego... We "belong to"  the unconscious, which came first, and which is fully conscious of itself.

Comment: i'm gonna delete for a bit, thanks